# Default checked checkbox not toggling on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-bootstrap

I am using Reactjs. I am working on creating a Modal form using `Modal from react-bootstrap`. I created a form using bootstrap. The form contains the checkbox that needs to be checked by default. So I used the `checked` property for the input checkbox. But the checkbox doesn't toggle when I click on it. I can't quite figure out the problem. Here is my code:

```
<Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.closeModal}>
<Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Create New User</Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body>

    <form class="form-horizontal" name="newUser">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="userName">User Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" ref="userName" placeholder="User Name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="password">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" ref="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="password">Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" ref="password" placeholder="Re-enter Password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="email">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ref="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox-inline">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="enabled" ref="enabled" value="enabled" checked/> Enabled </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-inline">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="locked" ref="locked" value="locked" /> Locked </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</Modal.Body>
<Modal.Footer>
    <Button onClick={this.submitUser} bsStyle="primary">Confirm</Button>
    <Button onClick={this.closeModal} bsStyle="warning">Cancel</Button>
</Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

Here is [image: Modal Image]. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Watch console log, React usually saying a lot of how to do with your components. In this case it says:

> Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `checked` prop to a form
>   field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only
>   field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise,
>   set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of
>   `FileList`.

So just:
`defaultChecked={this.state.enabled}` instead of `checked={this.state.enabled}`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I felt that "defaultChecked" was not working properly. So I used "checked" with "onChange" for toggling the state.

Eg.

```
checked={this.state.enabled} onChange={this.setState({enabled : !this.state.enabled})}
```